# Connect a repl to Charles Proxy

Tags: clojure, proxy, charles-proxy, cursive

I'm trying to debug my networked application to find out a network bug with one of my requests. Instead of using the command line, as the error happens inside a library, I'd rather use Charles Proxy for it.

My problem is that the connection is done by https and it's not visible as the REPL is not going through the proxy. I have tried to add -Dhttp.proxyHost and -Dhttp.proxyPort as parameters to the run/debug config to no avail.

Other applications are running through the proxy correctly.

What options am I missing?

[image: Error]

Comment: What http client library are you using?

Comment: Whatever this uses behind the scenes https://github.com/adamwynne/twitter-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the [http client library](https://github.com/cch1/http.async.client) used by [twitter-api](https://github.com/adamwynne/twitter-api) doesn't honor the JVM `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort` properties.

You could try add `:proxy {:host "localhost" :port 8888 :protocol :https}` as a named parameter to your twitter-api call.